# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.Android.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, syncfusion

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a SyncFusion List view (SfListView). It causes a frequent crash on Android with following error:

```
Unhandled exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
 Object name: 'Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.Android.ExtendedScrollViewRenderer'.
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00029] in <7cfbebb561c54efc9010b018c0846c7e>:0 
 at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00000] in <7cfbebb561c54efc9010b018c0846c7e>:0 
 at Android.Views.View.get_IsLayoutRequested () [0x0000a] in <9ef29c909d7e4606a46b131129da3975>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ScrollViewRenderer+<OnScrollToRequested>d__58.MoveNext () [0x000ce] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ScrollViewRenderer.cs:309 
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <9ef29c909d7e4606a46b131129da3975>:0 
at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <9ef29c909d7e4606a46b131129da3975>:0 
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <9ef29c909d7e4606a46b131129da3975>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:ab79b1ac-9c45-4d56-89ec-c42ce2376e50 (intptr,intptr)
```

I already contacted SyncFusion and they says its a framework issue.

The listview is rendered into a custom tabbed container.

Used with Xamarin.Forms 2.3 to 2.5 (latest) but still the issue is there.
Any suggestion or thoughts on this?

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could read  this : [System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79315/xamarin-forms-bug-system-objectdisposedexception-cannot-access-a-disposed-object).

### Solution 1 :

Explicitly set the `CachingStrategy` on the `ListView` to `RecycleElement`.

### Solution 2 :

You could try  changing the default `Garbage Bridge` collector. `Xamarin.Android` default is `Tarjan`, change it to  `new` GC Bridge and try again :

- Create a `environment.text` file within your `Xamarin.Android` project with the `BuildAction` set to `AndroidEnvironment`.
- Then you can specify which `GC_BRIDGE` option your application should use by passing `bridge-implementation=old`, `bridge-implementation=new`, or `bridge-implementation=tarjan` to the `MONO_GC_PARAMS` environment variable.

For example :

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=new
```

Then rebuild and test your project.

Refer to :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/#GC_Bridge_Options

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-improvements/

Comment: Solution1: is not possible because Syncfusion listview does not support that CachingStrategy property. I tried Solution2: but still my app is getting crashed

Answer (score 0):

Not the real fix, but I figured out `ListView` works in cases that `SfListView` does not - where it crashes just for Andriod.

**So I am using this to fix the issue:**

```
public class List :
#if __IOS__
    SfListView
#else
    ListView
#endif
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, there is a solution on [this thread](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms/issues/56), just check the comments. The source of the issue seems to be in a way how the ObservableCollection list is cleared; Instead of using .Clear() method, you should try with assigning it to new list:

So instead of:

```
ObservableCollectionProperty.Clear();
```

Use:

```
ObservableCollectionProperty = new ObservableCollection<TypeGoesHere>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Xamarin SyncFusion control from the Essential UI Kit: the **sfRotator** used in the Detail --> "Room Booking" template. It's the little "indicator dots" that's typically paired with a CarouselView.

The sfRotator was bound to an ObservableCollection property, and calling .Clear() caused the error. Simply assigning it a new value without Clearing it first fixed it, i.e., changing it from this:

```
Cards.Clear()
```

to this:

```
Cards = new ObservableCollection<Card>(cardList as List<Card>);
```